# WPF datagrid - event for when row is rendered in the background?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Using a DataGrid in WPF, we have a few events to intercept when a row is added, changed, etc...
But what I'm struggling with is the following scenario:

- Manually generate a list of objects
- Bind list to the datacontext of a grid
- Intercept `LoadingRow` event

After all LoadingRow events have passed the debugger, it still takes a long time until the grid is rendered on screen.
I actually want to intercept the debugger when a row is rendered in the background before the grid is visible. 
Is there an event that allows me to do that? As it takes longer to visually render each row, I want to be able to update my progress bar according to the rows rendered in the background and not just when a row is added to the `ItemsSource`.

I'm not that familiar with `DependencyObjects` and such, so if it's relevant I would like some good references on where to start reading.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between the `LoadingRow` event and when you say "when a row is rendered in the background before the grid is visible."  Isn't that the `LoadingRow` event?

Comment: That's what I expected too, but I'm binding a rather big list and I notice that there's still a lot of time between the loading of all rows and the rendering on screen

Comment: Okay, well I'd say it seems like there's nothing that can be done about that.  In WinForms DataGridView, there's the `RowPrePaint` event, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in WPF.

Comment: I do have a converter that changes the background of certain cells, maybe it's a good idea to use the dispatcher to send a status update to my progress bar from there?

Comment: I've tried using an indeterminate progress indicator but the rendering of the grid freezes the UI thread :(

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I'll post some code when I get home, but I don't think you'll find it useful.